# Why am I getting a jQuery Reference error after jQuery has loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I am getting an error on a simple jQuery test.  Please see the image to show the order of files loading and the fact that the jQuery is loaded before the error happens.

Here is my Content Page:

```
    <asp:Content
    ID="Content1"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"
    runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content
    ID="Content2"
    ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
    runat="server">

    <textarea id="txtArea"> hi </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
        $(function () {

            $('txtArea').val = "bye";
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

I have my scripts loaded at the end of my Master page, before the  closing tag.

Anyone know what is causing this simple error?

I don't think my image is uploading.  Here is the firebug results showing the library is loaded.

```
GET TestFolder/TestLoadingScriptsFromDifferentFolderLevel.aspx [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1351ms]
GET Styles/Site.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
GET WebResource.axd [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 351ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 405ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 417ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 338ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 285ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 394ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 380ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 419ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 61ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 57ms]
GET http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 129ms]
ReferenceError: $ is not defined TestLoadingScriptsFromDifferentFolderLevel.aspx:45
GET WebResource.axd [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
```

Comment: In the rendered source of the page, is the jquery script included above the snippet you've shown here? What does `console.log($, jQuery)` above the `$(function()...` line show you?

Comment: have you referenced jquery in your master page ?

Comment: may be the order of library is after the script provided.

Comment: Also check the loading order of your javascript files. jquery plugins (ui, validate, datatables) must be loaded after jquery itself. The error could be thrown there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line "I have my scripts loaded at the end of my Master page, before the closing tag." makes me think there in lies your issue.

Load the scripts at the top of your master page, this will fix your issue.

Comment: Exactly what Talspaugh said... You're running your page script before the end of the doc has been reahced and jQuery is loaded

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses.  That was the problem and makes sense.  I was reading that scripts should be loaded at the end of the document, and I don't know why I sheepishly did it.

Comment: You probably misread somewhere. Scripts should run after all their dependencies have loaded. A good way to ensure this is putting all of your code inside a wrapper that waits until the document is loaded. `$(document).ready(function(event){ /* Code goes here */ });` This allows you to avoid putting your code blocks at the end of the page (it's often best to put your code in the Head) but still waits until all the external JS is loaded.